# Proving associates in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $x,y\in R$ with $y^{2}=y$. Suppose $(x)=(y)$. Then how does one prove $x$ and $y$ are associates? Further, if $x^{n}$ and $y$ are associates then is it true that $x^{n+1}$ and $y$ are also associates? (Burton, *A First Course in Rings and Ideals*, Problem 1, Chapter 6.)

**Definition.** Two elements $a, b\in R$ are said to be associates if $a = bu$, where $u$ is an invertible element of $R$.

My attempts:

$(x)=(y)$ this gives $x=ay$ and also $y=bx$. Substituting we have $y=bay$. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x)=(y)$ implies $(x(y-1))=(y(y-1))=(0)$, hence $x(y-1)=0$.

This implies $x=(1-y+x)y$, we are left to show that $1-y+x$ is a unit.

If it is not a unit, we have some maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ with $y-1=x \mod \mathfrak m$, i.e.

$\mathfrak m + (y) = \mathfrak m + (x) = \mathfrak m + (y-1)$

This is a contradiction:

First case: $y \in \mathfrak m$, then the LHS is equal to $\mathfrak m$, while the RHS is equal to $R$.

Second case: $y \notin \mathfrak m$. We have $y(y-1)=0 \in \mathfrak m$ and deduce $y-1 \in \mathfrak m$. Thus the LHS is equal to $R$, while the RHS is equal to $\mathfrak m$.

---

For the follow up question, just note that we have

$(y)=(y^2)=(x^{2n}) \subset (x^{n+1}) \subset (x^n)=(y)$ and use the result above.

One should note that $n \geq 1$ is required. The assertion is obviously false for $n=0$.

Comment: More explicitly, you can argue that $1-y+x $ is invertible because $1-y+by$ is an inverse, where $b $ is such that $y=bx $.

Comment: Thanks for the explicit inverse. I was quite sure, that one can just write it down, but I couldn't come up with it, so I decided to do the abstract thingie.

Comment: This is a really interesting lemma that I apparently haven't heard before. The generators of a direct summand are all associates to the generating idempotent!